# Haar Cascade error while trying to make annotations

Tags: python, opencv

i am currently trying to make a Haar cascade xml on my laptop.I am beginner in this type of programming.I have a problem related to making annotations.Also if you guys have further advices i would be glad to receive them, i am trying to do it from 0 using only my laptop and the positives/negatives i have.

i tried this command :
opencv_annotation --annotations=positive_annotations.txt --images=positive_images --maxWindowHeight=800

i was expecting it to work but i got this error and i do not know how to solve it:
'opencv_annotation' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I added cv2 as a environment variable and i have the same error [cv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpWH3.png)

Comment: which opencv version are you using? Does the file opencv_annotation exist in your system?

Comment: I am using opencv 4.7.0.In fact you are right, it doesn't exist in my system. I read somewhere online that opencv deleted the function and i might need to go back to 3.4 opencv. Is this information correct?

Comment: I think that's correct. Afaik you can still use a trained cascade classifiers in 4.7 then, but you will need the training binaries from an older opencv version. I think I last used cascade classifier training binaries in 2.4.11 and never used the annotation binary. 3.4 might also be ok.

Comment: Yes, i will try going back to 3.4 and get back with the results. I am trying to make the xml file on my own to test how the dataset affects the cascade, thus why i am trying this method. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: you are welcome. In my project I didnt use the annotation binary because I annotated with a different tool and created the samples files programmatically. Maybe that's an option for you as well, but you wlll need the other binaries anyways.